# PostgreSQL issues in big production environment

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I really someone can help me out.
We have a PGSQL database running in a production environment. There are about 1000+ users, spread over +/- 20 terminal servers.

I'm running into few issues, but the biggest one is the open connections. When our application is opened, it automatically creates two connections to the PGSQL (two different databases). Our application is used embedded within +/- 15 applications of our client. In other words: every time they open an application (ours or an application which uses ours embedded), 2 connections to our PGSQL are being made.

Our application also has an Outlook plugin to save mails into our software. In other words: there are a lot of connections being opened and closed constantly.

The database of all their applications are on a AS400 system.

At first, there were 1000+ open connections in PGSQL. Every user logs in with their own username on the database. After some researching i've installed 'PGBOUNCER' for all the connections to one of our two databases. Now, there are 'only' +500 open connections on our PGSQL, so that worked.

Because there are constantly connections being opened and closed from the terminal server to the PGSQL (and the AS400), sometimes the connection can't be opened and throws an error:

> could not connect to server: Address already in use (0x00002740/10048)
> Is the server running on host "THEIR_SERVER" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 6432?

The 6432 is the pgbouncer port. Is this something with ephemeral ports running out? I don't know much about this. What can I do to fix this?

Is the problem really too much connections at a time?
Too much connections being opened and closed?
Would it be better if users didn't have their own database login? Maybe that's a possibility for users 'sharing' their postgres connection?

Also, because there are alot of connections open at any time on the PGSQL, the CPU is running at 85-100% usage all the time. The database is ALOT slower when alot of users are logged in.

Database server has 16 GB of ram and 4 CPU cores.
I just modified the postgres.conf to get a bigger shared_buffer & work_mem in hope this will prevent the database slowing down that much when alot of users are logged in.

Hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: 4 CPUs will never be able to properly cope with 500+ connections. If you really can't get that number down, you should definitely upgrade the hardware and maybe consider upgrading to Postgres 14 which improved significantly when dealing with many connections

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'll ask for at least 2 more cores. Can I expect issues updating v13 to v14?

Comment: Upgrading to a new major version is never without risk. I wouldn't expect any big issues though, but your environment seems to really benefit from that improvement. You can read up incompatible changes [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/#id-1.11.6.5.4). The first bug fix version (14.1) is due in about 4 weeks.

Comment: An open connection hardly requires CPU.  But opening a connection is quite another matter.  Are the application capable of reusing an open connection, ie. persistent connections?  The difference may be night and day.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille You mean connections between applications? Never tried it but I should check if it's even possible. Isn't that what PGbouncer provides? Reusing connections so it doensn't have to open a new one every time someone runs an application?

Comment: Connection between the application and the database.  Sometimes - eg. with web applications, as they often carry no state - a connection is established and closed for each database request they make.  This is an enormous waste of resources, and so most database drivers have a means to work with persistent connections.  Even though the application opens and closes a connection, the driver doesn't really execute those commands, but hands the application an existing connection and doesn't close it afterwards.  Eg. with PostgreSQL, it's enough to put "P:" before the connection string.

Comment: You have described why so many connections exist.  But you haven't described why they are created and destroyed with reckless abandon.  Why, once an application is open, doesn't it stay open for long time?

Comment: "AS400"  Doesn't that make it at least 23 years old?

Comment: @jjanes I did not describe why so many connections exist. I couldn't, not knowing the applications running.  I gave the example of a web server environment, where an application is "open" (running) for the duration of a single request (each perhaps lasting milliseconds, but thousands simultaneously).  One of the main defences here is a reverse proxy, to avoid starting an application when static content is requested.

Comment: @jjanes Every time our application is opened (seperatly or embedded) we keep the connection open until they close the application. So we don't create a connection for every call.

All the open connections exist because there are that many users. Connections are opened/closed constantly because they just open and close applications all the time. For example: if they want to save a mail, we open a 'light' version of our application. Users fill in some data and save the mail. After this, our application is closed again. So for each mail they save they use two connections.

Comment: AS400 is old but still very powerful.

Comment: @Morph Do you have statistics about the number of connections opened, eg. per minute?  How do the application connect to the database?  What OS is the database running on?